# ¿A qué se debe el error ""node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable."?

Tags: nodejs, npm

Estoy ejecutando `npm run dev` y me aparece el siguiente error:

```
npm run dev

> prueba-git@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\sibarra\Documents\prueba-git
> lite-server

""node"" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 9009
npm ERR! prueba-git@1.0.0 dev: `lite-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 9009
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the prueba-git@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sibarra\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-20T12_09_32_360Z-debug.log
```

alguien sabe a que se puede deber?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Espero que sea lo mismo ayer a mi me dio este error en c# **lo solvente compilando las librerias en 64 bits por lo que entendí el conjunto de instrucciones que se usaba era de 32** y no era capaz en mi caso de encontrar la palabra cluster

otra opción es que revises si los comandos los estas lanzando como 32 bits y no como 64

Comment: Por favor a menos que sea absolutamente necesario, no usemos imágenes para responder

Comment: @BetaM l habia añadido con el fin de que pudiera ver que la consola se lanzaba en 32 y no en 64 pero la elimino (para mi era necesaria)

Answer (score 1):

Ese mensaje se da cuando no tienes dicho programa en la variable de entorno 'path' de Windows. npm = node package manager, es decir necesitas tener instalado node.

- Comprueba que la variable path contiene la ruta correcta a node
- Si ya tenias node instalado, por algun motivo la instalación está corrupta, prueba a reinstalarlo.